# qt Project Files

Tags: qt

I have a bunch of .pro files. Along with this is a file called bld_Odyssey_read (I think that's important but I don't know why). In that file are the following lines:

```
; batch file to make save file for Odyssey I/O utilities
; @bld_odyssey_read  to execute

.compile OpenOdysseyFile.pro
.compile OpenPatientIndex.pro
.compile OpenClinicalIndex.pro
.compile ody_mul_cnvrt.pro
.compile pickpick.pro
```

I can't figure out how to compile these files. I know they are qt project files (correct me if I'm wrong). I downloaded the qt editor, but I can't figure out what to do with them. I am much more used to visual studio, but I understand the qt plug-in isn't compatible with vs express. If someone could point me in the right direction so I can turn these into executable programs, I would greatly appreciate it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how that batch file works (what is `.compile`?) but here is how you can build everything (one example - do the same for each .pro file):

```
qmake OpenOdysseyFile.pro CONFIG+=release
make
```

Comment: where do I run qmake (and make) from? I'm running Win64. I have cygwin (so I think that's where I run make from, right?), but qmake isn't recognized.

Comment: You can do it from `cmd`. Just add path to qmake (something like "C:\Qt-4.8.4\bin") to your system PATH variable.

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem is actually the file itself. I'm getting errors everywhere, mostly "extra characters after test expression." It appears they've used semicolons for comments (and I don't think that's correct). So I may have to tinker with the file. Thanks for your help.